# Connecting TradingView Email Signals to MT4

Tags: python, c++, websocket, tradingview-api, mql4

I don't have much knowledge about coding, but I tried experimenting with some research. I want to enable TradingView Email signals on MT4, but although the emails are being read, they are not being executed on MT4. I would be very happy if you could help me with this.

```
import imaplib
import email
import zmq
import random
import datetime, time
from email.header import decode_header

volume = '0.1'
user = ''
pwd = ''

c = zmq.Context()

print("Connecting to the mt4 server...")
s = c.socket(zmq.REQ)
s.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555") # Bu bağlantı noktası belki değiştirilmeli

r = c.socket(zmq.PULL)
r.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556") # Diğer bir port numarası


def generate_nonce(length=8):
    """Generate pseudorandom number."""
    return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])


def trade(signal,volume,pair):
    try:
        trade = 'TRADE|OPEN|' + signal + '|' + pair + '|0|0|0|IcarusBot Trade|' + generate_nonce() + '|' + volume
        s.send_string(trade, encoding='utf-8')
        print("Waiting for metatrader to respond...")
        m = s.recv()
        print("Reply from server ", m)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
print("Listening to email server...")


def readmail(volume):
    # print("Sleeping 3 Seconds")
    time.sleep(0.1)

    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.yandex.com")
    m.login(user, pwd)
    m.select('INBOX')
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
    resp, items = m.search(None,
                           f'NOT SEEN FROM tradingview SENTON "{today}"')
    items = items[0].split()
    for emailid in items:
        resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
        email_body = data[0][1]
        mail = email.message_from_bytes(email_body)  # mail değişkenini tanımlama
        try:
            subject = mail['Subject']
            if subject is not None:
                print(subject)  # Kontrol amaçlı eklendi
                subject_parts = subject.split()
                pair = None
                for part in subject_parts:
                    if part == "XAUUSD":
                        pair = part
                    if part == "Buy":
                        m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')
                        print(subject + ' \x1b[6;30;42m' + 'Buy' + '\x1b[0m' + ' Triggered on ' + pair)
                        trade('0', volume, pair)
                    elif part == "Sell":
                        m.store(emailid, '+FLAGS', '\\Seen')
                        print(subject + ' \x1b[6;30;41m' + 'Sell' + '\x1b[0m' + ' Triggered on ' + pair)
                        trade("1", volume, pair)
            else:
                print("Subject is None.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)




while True:
    readmail(volume)
```

The code I want to run is this. I am running the code, it is fetching the subject of the emails, but it is not executing on MT4.